# Development and Adhoc apps on the same iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Due to the nature of Apple Push Notification security credentials, I have to have two servers (one development and one production) and the development version of the app points to the development server and the adhoc version of the app points to the production server.

I want to be able to have both the dev and adhoc versions to exist on my own phone at the same time for testing purposes. Is there setting in the info.plist excluding the Bundle Identifier which will allow me to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install two apps with the same bundle identifier on 1 single device.
Look at this question: [Installing different versions of the same iPhone project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933419/installing-different-versions-of-the-same-iphone-project).

I faced this situation too and finally created a new app id for the AdHoc version.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating a new throw-away App ID for the development version.  Keep the Ad Hoc version as close as possible to your final distribution release.

I preferred not to create a new app ID, and instead tested on two different sets of devices.  But that wasn't your question.